# SQL group by NULL/ NOT NULL

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
id name facebookid linkedinid  googleid                                                 
-- ---- ---------- ----------  -------- 
1  john  123456xde  NULL        345ft566     
2  peter NULL       NULL        4563erf
3  suma  df3466     yh4566      NULL
4  rick  NULL       34Nh6       NULL
5  ronny NULL       NULL        NULL
6  susan NULL       NULL        3456
```

I want to know how many users are registered using linkedin, google , facebook and also how may have not connected any network at all.

Expected result :

```
facebook linkedin google direct
-------- -------- ------ -----
 2          2         3      1
```

SQL query would be great but I am looking to learn how to approach this .

Thanks

EDIT :

I have tried

```
SELECT count(facebookid), count(linkedinid), count(googleid) FROM user;
```

Comment: show us what you have tried

Comment: @LuthandoLoot done.. thanks

Comment: why downvote ? I have posted my try.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
    select 
count(facebookid) "linkedinid", 
count(linkedinid) "linkedinid", 
count(googleid) "googleid", 
count(case 
         when facebookid is null 
              and linkedinid is null 
              and googleid is null then 1 else null end) direct
from your_table
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. is it possible to try this by group by ? or that doesn't apply ?

Comment: Shouldn't be any problems.